# Preference class override default behaviour

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I dislike the way the Android `SharedPreferences` class works. 
My main reason is you have to specify a default value everytime you look for a key-value pair in any part of your application. Given the fact most applications will probably call these values in multiple places, this approach really kind of promotes errors in expected application/ preference behaviour, because there's no central point to fetch your *default*  settings. Example: Activity A getBoolean(key133, false), Actvity B getBoolean(key133, true): problems.

I circumvented this problem by specifying/ storing my required application preference values in a `HashMap`, and  I have a custom `SharedPreferences` derived class which lazily looks for the default value in the specified `HashMap`s. I just call say a MyClass.getBoolean(key) or a MyClass.getString(key), and it looks for the default value in the `HashMap`, returning and storing (.commit()-ing) it if it doesn't exist yet. The default behaviour would be to call `getBoolean(key, default_value)`. This is also benificial to performance, because storing ALL preferences upon application initialisation is pretty bad performance wise.

One problem solved, but now I have a new one: all `Preference` derived classes can't find the default values, because I can't use my own `SharedPreference` derived way to query for the default application settings. This leads to my application working fine, but my settings not actually showing the default values, because they aren't (always) stored yet upon first opening the settings pages...

Long story short: how do I override the `Preference` class to prevent this?

EDIT: some code to explain the problem and why I chose this way

```
private final static Context context                    = ApplicationSubclass.getApplicationContext_();
private final static SharedPreferences prefs            = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);  
private final static SharedPreferences.Editor editor    = prefs.edit();
public static Map<String, Boolean> booleans             = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
public static Map<String, Integer> longs                = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
public static Map<String, String> strings               = new HashMap<String, String>();
public static Map<String, Integer> integers             = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public aPreferences(){
    initialise();
}//end constructor

public void initialise(){
    // setup default preferences
    setBooleans();
    //setLongs();
    setStrings();
    //setIntegers();
}//end method   

private void setBooleans(){
    booleans.put("does_this_work", true);
    booleans.put("is_it_easy", true);
    booleans.put("is_it_free_of_problems", false);
    // and some hundreds more
}//end method

private void setStrings(){
    strings.put("show_me", "Show me!");
    // and some hundreds more
}//end method

// work the magic here
public boolean getBoolean(String key){
    if (!prefs.contains(key)) putBoolean(key, booleans.get(key));
    return prefs.getBoolean(key, booleans.get(key));
}//end method

public void putBoolean(String key, boolean value){
    editor.putBoolean(key, value).commit();
}//end method
```

This works:

```
private static aPreferences values = new aPreferences();
if (values.getBoolean("does_this_work")) // value initialised upon first access
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), values.getString("show_me"));
```

This doesn't:

```
CheckBoxPreference sound = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
sound.setKey("does_this_work"); // value not initialised, so checkbox not checked
sound.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.sound_title));
sound.setSummary(getResources().getString(R.string.sound_text));
root.addPreference(sound);
```

Comment: AFAIK, you don't. First, you would have to override each `Preference` subclass. Second, I have not been successful in getting the preference screen system to use anything other than stock implementations of `SharedPreferences` (e.g., my own encrypted `SharedPreferences` implementation). BTW, wouldn't it have been simpler for you just to use static data members for the defaults, or call `setDefaultValues()` to use the defaults defined in your preference XML files?

Comment: some good points here. I could have used static data members, but I am using `HashMap`s exactly because I did use to have a `setDefaultValues()` method, which would iterate over the maps and write the values. But I noticed it would take anywhere up to 5 seconds to write the preferences. So now I am initiliasing the values only on first access, which `Preference` classes don't understand...

Comment: plus, I have a couple of hundred preference values...using static data members is just a little to much hassle

Comment: I think I am going to have to override each of the `Preference` subclasses. It's not that much work. Come to think of it, my safest bet would probably be to override the `setDefaultValue(Object defaultValue)` method. What do you think @CommonsWare?

Comment: Haven't tried that. Sounds plausible, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually recommend creating your own preference-management class to handle things like this. You can set your own global get / set methods and expose the default values as public static fields if you need to know what the defaults were. Something like this:

```
public class MyPreferences {

    private static final String INT_VALUE_1_KEY = "VALUE_1";
    public static final int INT_VALUE_1_DEFAULT = -1;

    public static void setDefaults(Context c) {
       SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
       Editor edit = prefs.edit();

       if (!prefs.contains(INT_VALUE_1_KEY)) {
          edit.putInt(INT_VALUE_1_KEY, INT_VALUE_1_DEFAULT);
       }
       // etc..

       edit.commit();
    }

    public static int getValue1(Context c) {
       SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
       return prefs.getInt(INT_VALUE_1_KEY, INT_VALUE_1_DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but that's kind of what I did, and my problem is that any class based on `Preference` doesn't know how to handle this way of storing application preferences. 
Using those classes is great, because you're not required to specify the default value, they will just look into the `SharedPreferences` for the value. But the value has to be there otherwise it leads to settings screens looking wrong...

Comment: Ahh, quite right - if you're using a PreferenceScreen / CheckBoxPreference / EditTextPreference, etc., I guess you would have to initialize first. What if you kicked off an AsyncTask in your Application that would call MyPreferences.setDefaults(Context) in a background thread on the first run?